# The rendered animation didn't come out rendered

Tags: animation

So I wasted a few hours just to wait for it to render a 150-frame animation but the result is the default layout animation rather than the rendered one. And I'm very frustrated. I wasted my 2 hours just like that. Can anybody help me?

[image]

That's what I get from 2 hours of waiting.

[image]

This is the picture render and what im expecting from the animation.

Comment: Add a picture of your render..

Comment: I added the pic

Comment: How your render output is with camera?

Comment: I don't know.  I only click the "animation" button on the side panel or whatever its name is and waited for it to render frame by frame.

Comment: I'm rendering back the animation to see if the problem persists

Comment: Yes please, because I can't spot anything incorrect as your render in blender is right, but not in output, how this may be possible?

Comment: What was created in your Output folder? and does Render->Play Rendered Animation show your animation?

Comment: Don't waste hours rendering animations just ti find out there are errors... render as an image sequence and encode later.

Comment: I rendered it back and it works this time. Thanks anyways. I think it was a logical error, such a waste of my 2 hours. But I have another question, how do you save it into video file?

Comment: Change File format from PNG to FF-Mpeg and encoding container from Matroska to Mpeg-4 and you will get a video output!